# WebSocket Java Play chat multi rooms

Tags: java, websocket, server, chat

I followed an example to create a chat room and everything went fine. Now I have to implement a chat with a multi room. How can I adapt this code so I can handle multi chat rooms? I searched a lot on the internet but I didn't find anything.

```
package controllers;

import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.event.LoggingAdapter;
import akka.japi.Pair;
import akka.japi.pf.PFBuilder;
import akka.stream.Materializer;
import akka.stream.javadsl.*;
import play.libs.F;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.Logger;

import akka.event.Logging;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

/**
 * A very simple chat client using websockets.
 */
public class HomeController extends Controller {

    private final Flow userFlow;

    @Inject
    public HomeController(ActorSystem actorSystem,
                          Materializer mat) {
        org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

       actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("Chat");
        LoggingAdapter logging = Logging.getLogger(actorSystem.eventStream(), logger.getName());
        //noinspection unchecked
        Source<String, Sink<String, NotUsed>> source = MergeHub.of(String.class)
                .log("source", logging)
                .recoverWithRetries(-1, new PFBuilder().match(Throwable.class, e -> Source.empty()).build());
        Sink<String, Source<String, NotUsed>> sink = BroadcastHub.of(String.class);

        Pair<Sink<String, NotUsed>, Source<String, NotUsed>> sinkSourcePair = source.toMat(sink, Keep.both()).run(mat);
        Sink<String, NotUsed> chatSink = sinkSourcePair.first();
        Source<String, NotUsed> chatSource = sinkSourcePair.second();
        this.userFlow = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(chatSink, chatSource).log("userFlow", logging);
    }

    public Result index() {
        Http.Request request = request();
        String url = routes.HomeController.chat().webSocketURL(request);
        return Results.ok(views.html.index.render(url));
    }

    public WebSocket chat() {
        return WebSocket.Text.acceptOrResult(request -> {

          Logger.error("Alguem chegou");

          //   if (sameOriginCheck(request)) {
//                 return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(F.Either.Right(userFlow));
//             } else {
//                 return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(F.Either.Left(forbidden()));
//             }
         return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(F.Either.Right(userFlow));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the WebSocket comes from the same origin.  This is necessary to protect
     * against Cross-Site WebSocket Hijacking as WebSocket does not implement Same Origin Policy.
     *
     * See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-1.3 and
     * http://blog.dewhurstsecurity.com/2013/08/30/security-testing-html5-websockets.html
     */
   //  private boolean sameOriginCheck(Http.RequestHeader request) {
//         String[] origins = request.headers().get("Origin");
//         if (origins.length > 1) {
//             // more than one origin found
//             return false;
//         }
//         String origin = origins[0];
//         return originMatches(origin);
//     }

    private boolean originMatches(String origin) {
        if (origin == null) return false;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(origin);
            return url.getHost().equals("localhost")
                    && (url.getPort() == 9000 || url.getPort() == 19001);
        } catch (Exception e ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I am sorry, but no. Actually I migrated to Spring...

Comment: Yeah I am creating a websocket using Spring Boot for Java app and it works successfully. But I can't find anywhere how to create separate channels (rooms) for a websocket...